# sqlQuery string wtih Ajax

Tags: javascript, sql, ajax, vb.net

I'm trying to do an Ajax call with a query string however I got halfway through now stuck on what to do, I'm trying to update a SQL table with javascript sortable function. once the item has moved up or down then I pass through the ajax and get it to update in the SQL. (well that what I'm trying to do anyway)
Was wondering if you guys can help.

```js
  <script>
      $("#tableBody").sortable({
          connectWith: "#tableBody",
          update: function (event, ui) {
              // this.id = #tableBody
              //  ui.item = Dragged item
              console.log(ui.item.attr("data-id"));
              console.log(ui.item.attr("data-prod-id"));
              console.log(ui.item.index());
            $.get('shop_prod_options_update_sort_order.aspx?id=' + id + '&prodid=' + prodid + '&sortorder=' + sortorder);
          }
      });
  </script>
```

```html
<Script Language="VB" RunAt="Server">

    Dim intOptionId As Integer = 1
    Dim intProdId As Integer = 1
    Dim intNewSortOrder As Integer = 0
    Dim intOldSortOrder As Integer = 0

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If IsNumeric(Request.QueryString("id")) Then
            intOptionId = Val(Request.QueryString("id"))
        End If

        If Request.QueryString("sortorder") = "sortorder" Then
            intOptionId = True
        Else
            intOptionId = False
        End If

        If Not IsPostBack Then

            UpdateList()

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateList()

        Dim connDBConnection As SqlConnection = Nothing
        Dim commDBCommand As SqlCommand
        Dim strSQLQuery As String = ""

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Try

            strSQLQuery =   "SELECT option_order FROM shop_option WHERE option_id = @option_id"
            Using connConnnection As New SqlConnection(Database.GetDatabaseConnString)
                connConnnection.Open()
                Using commCommand As New SqlCommand(strSQLQuery,connConnnection)
                    commCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@option_id", intOptionId)
                    intOldSortOrder = commCommand.ExecuteScalar()
                End Using
            End Using


            If intOldSortOrder>intNewSortOrder Then
                strSQLQuery =   "UPDATE option_order FROM shop_option WHERE option_id = @option_id", intOptionId
                strSQLQuery +=   "SET option_order = option_order + 1 FROM shop_option WHERE option_id = @option_id", intOptionId
            Else
                strSQLQuery =   "UPDATE option_order FROM shop_option WHERE option_id = @option_id;", intOptionId
                strSQLQuery +=   "SET option_order = option_order - 1 FROM shop_option WHERE option_id = @option_id", intOptionId
            End If

            Using connConnnection As New SqlConnection(Database.GetDatabaseConnString)
                connConnnection.Open()
                Using commCommand As New SqlCommand(strSQLQuery,connConnnection)
                    commCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@option_id", intOptionId)
                    intOldSortOrder = commCommand.ExecuteScalar()
                End Using
            End Using


        Catch ex As Exception

        Finally
            Database.Disconnect(connDBConnection)
        End Try

    End Sub
</script>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
       
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
                
                
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the problem I'm having is, I get a list from the database. With the sortable in javascript which allows me to drag and drop the items in the list. Trying to update the database from an ajax call and set the new moved item in to be set in the database. Hope that makes sense

Comment: An empty `Catch` is the devil's workshop.

Comment: What is this line doing? `strSQLQuery = "UPDATE option_order FROM shop_option WHERE option_id = @option_id", intOptionId` I don't think that will compile.

Comment: `strSQLQuery +=   "SET option_order = option_order + 1 FROM shop_option WHERE option_id = @option_id", intOptionId` Again, this won't compile. The ampersand is the string concatenation operator in vb.net. Although "+" will work you can get unexpected results. Adding this string to the first one will not make a valid sql command.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the `Page_Load` stuff but I have tidied up the `UpdateList()` method.

Combined the connection and command into a single `Using` block.

Changed the `.AddWithValue` to `.Add` method. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

Moved the connection`.Open` to directly before the `.Execute`.

The `.ExecuteScalar` method returns an object so I added `CInt` to satisfy `Option Strict`.

Corrected your `Update` syntax.

An update command is not performed with `.ExecuteScalar` but with `.ExecuteNonQuery`.

Got rid of the `Try...Catch...Finally` since it wasn't doing anything but swallowing errors. Since you are using `Using` blocks I have no idea what `Database.Disconnect(connDBConnection)` was supposed to do.

```
Dim intOptionId As Integer = 1
Dim intProdId As Integer = 1
Dim intNewSortOrder As Integer = 0
Dim intOldSortOrder As Integer = 0

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Integer.TryParse(Request.QueryString("id"), intOptionId)
    'Not sure what you are doing here but intOptionID is declared as an Integer
    'and cannot take a Boolean value.
    'If Request.QueryString("sortorder") = "sortorder" Then
    '    intOptionId = True
    'Else
    '    intOptionId = False
    'End If
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        UpdateList()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateList()
    Dim strSQLQuery = "SELECT option_order FROM shop_option WHERE option_id = @option_id"
    Using connConnnection As New SqlConnection(Database.GetDatabaseConnString),
                commCommand As New SqlCommand(strSQLQuery, connConnnection)
        commCommand.Parameters.Add("@option_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intOptionId
        connConnnection.Open()
        intOldSortOrder = CInt(commCommand.ExecuteScalar())
    End Using
    If intOldSortOrder > intNewSortOrder Then
        strSQLQuery = "UPDATE shop_option SET option_order = option_order + 1 WHERE option_id = @option_id"
    Else
        strSQLQuery = "UPDATE shop_option SET option_order = option_order - 1 WHERE option_id = @option_id;"
    End If
    Using connConnnection As New SqlConnection(Database.GetDatabaseConnString),
                commCommand As New SqlCommand(strSQLQuery, connConnnection)
        commCommand.Parameters.Add("@option_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intOptionId
        connConnnection.Open()
        commCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```